# how to handle mongoDB close in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

All:

I am pretty new to mongoose, right now, I open MongoDB like:

**db.js**

```
var DB_URL = "mongodb://localhost/test/";

var mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect(DB_URL);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function (callback) {
    console.log("OPEN DB...");
});

module.exports = mongoose;
```

I wonder: Is there anything I must do if I terminate Application using that mongoose connection by simply with CTRL+C? Will MongoDB know this connection has been closed( or how can I inform this)?

This is especially helpful during DEV phase which the App may need to restart a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well here is an idea that I think might be helpful. Node.js receives unix signals. So for example Ctrl+C sends a unix signal (SIGINT) to the Node.js application you're running in that terminal to terminate.

Say you wanted to close your DB connection before shutting the node.js app. That way you can prevent lose of or damaging data. Well, a good way to do so is override the termination signal.

To override the signal all you have to do is this:

```
process.on('SIGINT', function(params) {
    //Shut your db instance here. 
    //close or save other stuff. 
});
```

This way when you do CTRL+C it will shut things gracefully without risking damage.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. There is one question: where should I put this part, inside the app.js(main handler file) or db.js?

Comment: Add it in the app.js.

Comment: Also don't forgot you're gonna need to throw code in there to kill the process too. Just heads up. :)

Comment: Thanks, could you tell me what code should I need to "kill the process"? Also when I put db.connection.close() in SIGINT function, It terminate the application immediately without the result of DB disconnection, how do I know if the DB close successfully before the application shut down?

Comment: Ok to remember, if you say db.connection.close() you have to pass a callback into that function. In that function you say process.exit(1); You can put a small console log before that to see if your signal is being received.

Comment: Thanks, I did that, but the application still shutdown before that callback executed, I use something like: process.on('SIGINT', function(params) {
    //Shut your db instance here. 
    //close or save other stuff. 
    app.db.disconnect(function(){
      console.log("Close DB...");
      process.exit(1);
    });
});
But that "Close DB..." never print out! I can only tell the connections are closed from mongoDB's console message.

Comment: What db npm are you using ?

Comment: that app is express(), db is require("mongoose"), and I add app.db = db;

Comment: `
process.on('SIGINT', function () {
    db.diconnect(function () {
        process.exit(1);
    });
});
`

Comment: Went to mongoose API found the disconnect function there, which takes in a call back. I call the process.exit in the callback.

Comment: Thanks, but I guess I use the same thing as yours( the only diff is I append the db to app ), and it does not work on my side.

Comment: Something is off here. You should look into what's up with that callback. I feel like you might be doing something wrong.